# RegEx matching for custom shortodes using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to implement some shortcodes into a WYSIWYG editor which will later be replaced by dynamic content. I can't seem to get the regex code working correctly.

I've tried countless different links from Google but nothing seems to match my exact issue.

My string:

> Project Information: [sc id=15]number of properties[\sc] test [sc
>   id=15]number of items[\sc]

The development requires the following testing:

```
Walls: [sc id=12]number of walls[\sc]
```

My code:

```
preg_match_all('/[sc id=[0-9]+](.*?)[\/sc]/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I would like to first get the id number, then replace the entire shortcode with a dynamic string coming from my database.

This is what I am currently getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  [sc id=15]number of properties
            [1] => sc] tes
            [2] =>  [sc id=15]number of items
            [3] =>  [sc id=12]number of walls
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => number of propertie
            [1] =>  te
            [2] => number of item
            [3] => number of wall
        )

)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `[` as `\[` for making it meaning literal match to `[` and also one more issue is there in your regex where you have written `\/` in `[\/sc]` instead of `\\`. You can use this regex, which correctly matches the way you expected.

```
\[sc id=[0-9]+\](.*?)\[\\sc\]
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lk65J9/1)**

Here is a **[PHP Code demo](https://rextester.com/TUGS59614)**

```
$input_lines = "Project Information: [sc id=15]number of properties[\sc] test [sc id=15]number of items[\sc]


The development requires the following testing:
Walls: [sc id=12]number of walls[\sc]";
preg_match_all('/\[sc id=([0-9]+)\](.*?)\[\\\\sc\]/', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Prints,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [sc id=15]number of properties[\sc]
            [1] => [sc id=15]number of items[\sc]
            [2] => [sc id=12]number of walls[\sc]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => number of properties
            [1] => number of items
            [2] => number of walls
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This certainly works better than my code, but I need it to return the id number rather than the string enclosed. Any ideas how to get this out?

Comment: @ScottBowers: Sure its easy. Just need to group the id string. Use this regex `\[sc id=([0-9]+)\](.*?)\[\\sc\]` and get id from group1. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lk65J9/2/) Let me know if this is what you wanted?